# Style changes after NPM run prod

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, styles

I have Laravel project with SASS. The thing is that I noticed when I run NPM RUN PROD there is a significant difference in how the site looks like - the font size changes and some things shift. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that all files are compiled and moved to the correct folders? How does your webpack file look like?

Comment: There might be some problem in minification and optimization. Check webpack config.